# R shiny using iframe for local files

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I would like to have a tab in my shiny app link to an R help file on my local machine. Here is my attempt:

In server.r:

```
output$help <- renderUI({
  tags$iframe(
  seamless="seamless",
  src="file:///usr/lib64/R/library/r_package/html/r_function.html")
})
```

In ui.r:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(id="tabSelected",
  tabPanel("Help", htmlOutput('help')))
)
```

I am basically seeing a blank page. I replaced the link above with a pdf from a webpage and it shows it fine. So I am guessing it has something to do with how I am importing the local html file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use `addResourcePath` to do the needful. This will map the paths. accordingly. Adding them to the `www` folder will also work, but you would need to move the files first.

```
addResourcePath("library", "~/lib64/R/library")
output$help <- renderUI({
  tags$iframe(
  seamless="seamless",
  src="library/r_package/html/r_function.html")
})
```

Comment: Adding html files to the www folder and then referencing those files via the `src` parameter does not work -- at least for Shiny 1.7.5.1.

Answer (score 3):

When pages are loaded with a HTTP(S) protocol (the case of the Shiny app) for security reasons you can't framed locals files with their `file:` URLs. If you want to display locals files you should access to them with a `http(s):` URL, so you have to save them in your www directory (a local web server) and access to files with their `http(s):` URLs (the URL will be something like `http://localhost/.../r_function.html`).